Excel VBA for selecting random rows from a list at set time daily
I have an excel sheet for my work with all the items we sell and every day we do something called a 10 line count and I would like the excel sheet to update on it's own picking 10 random products to be counted and each day they are different.
Id like it so at a set time of day the VBA kicks in and changes what needs to be counted.
The items what need to be counted are on a different sheet to the 10 line count so the full list of items are on a page called "Specimens Back Office Feed" and the 10 line (where the 10 items need to be pasted) are on a page called "Today's 10 Line"
The rows what need to be copied are from A2:G2 and go down all the way down to G500.
If someone could help me create a VBA what does this for me I'd be so greatful.
I have tired creating this myself over the last week but there seems to be faults all the time.
Private Sub auto_open() 
    MsgBox "New 10 line updated!" 
End Sub 

Sub getting_new_specimens() 
' ' getting_new_specimens Macro ' ' 
    Range( _ "A3:G3,A7:G7,A10:G10,A12:G12,A14:G14,A20:G20,A17:G17,A15:G15,A5:G5,A23:G23"). _ 
    Select 
    Range("A23").Activate 
    Selection.Copy 
    Sheets("Today's 10 Line").Select 
    Range("A8:G18").Select 
    ActiveSheet.Paste 
End Sub 

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean) 
    If Saved = False Then 
        ActiveWorkbook.Save 
    End If 
End Sub


Try this out:
Sub PickRandomLines()
    Const NUM_ITEMS As Long = 10 '# of random rows to pick
    Dim wsSpec As Worksheet, wsTen As Worksheet, rng As Range, firstRow As Long
    Dim dict As Object, r As Long, cDest As Range, lastRow As Long, numRows As Long
    
    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    Set wsSpec = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Specimens Back Office Feed")
    Set wsTen = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Todays 10 Line")
    
    firstRow = 2
    lastRow = wsSpec.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = wsSpec.Range("A" & firstRow & ":G" & lastRow)      'source range
    numRows = rng.Rows.Count
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set cDest = wsTen.Range("A2")             'paste starting here
    Do While dict.Count < NUM_ITEMS           'loop until 10 rows copied
        r = RandomBetween(1, numRows)         'pick random row number (exclude header)
        If Not dict.Exists(r) Then            'not already picked?
            rng.Rows(r).Copy cDest            'copy this row
            Set cDest = cDest.Offset(1)       'next paste location
            dict.Add r, True                  'remember this row
            If dict.Count = numRows Then Exit Do  'in case fewer rows than NUM_ITEMS
        End If
    Loop
End Sub

Function RandomBetween(min As Long, max As Long) As Long
    RandomBetween = min + Int((1 + max - min) * Rnd())
End Function


